# Left Join between two databases using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join

I have two databases and I am trying to compare two tables. My code does not seem to be working, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
/* 
 * This code compares between two tables
 */

//SQL call
$getData = $connection->prepare("SELECT `CustomerCity` FROM `auth` LEFT JOIN `tb_data.cobs.city` WHERE `CustomerCity` =  `tb_data.cobs.city` LIMIT 3");
$getData->execute();
$gotData = $getData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($gotData);
```

In my database I have two tables, on is cobs, the other is tb_data. tb_data has a table called cobs and auth is a table within a database called d_data. Both of these tables have a city column. I need get every record in auth that has a city that matches in the cobs table.

Comment: Don't just say that it's not working.  Say what _is_ happening and how that differs from the expected result.  Are you getting an error?  If so, what's the error?  If not, what's the value of `$gotData`?

Comment: what is tb_data.cobs.city ?

Comment: your query wrong and not clear, what is this tb_data.cobs.city?

Comment: `\`tb_data.cobs.city\``, quoted in that way, would reference a *single* identifier (e.g. a table or column) whose name happens to contain `.` characters.  If you want to quote the components of a qualified identifier, then each component should be quoted separately: e.g. `\`db\`.\`table\`.\`column\`` etc; however, in this case, there's no benefit to quoting (since each component comprises neither special characters nor reserved words). Nevertheless you appear to be using that same identifier in different places to refer to both a table and a column, so you'll need to fix that misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry I was not as specific as I needed to be. I just updated my question

Comment: Is `tb_data` a database or a table?  First you refer to it as a table, "In my database I have two tables, on is cobs, the other is tb_data" and then you seem to refer to it as a database "tb_data has a table called cobs".

Comment: My guess would be that you're after ``SELECT `auth`.`CustomerCity` FROM `auth` LEFT JOIN `tb_data`.`cobs` ON `auth`.`CustomerCity` =  `tb_data`.`cobs`.`city` LIMIT 3``.  Each and every backtick in this case is superfluous, and was only adding to your confusion.  Perhaps get rid of them all: ``SELECT auth.CustomerCity FROM auth LEFT JOIN tb_data.cobs ON auth.CustomerCity =  tb_data.cobs.city LIMIT 3``?

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that your query is wrong, but have not provided a correct answer. This is what you are likely looking for:

```
SELECT `auth.CustomerCity` FROM `auth` 
LEFT JOIN `tb_data.cobs` ON `tb_data.cobs.city` = `auth.CustomerCity` 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the query is using a mixture of explicit join syntax with obsolescent syntax for the join using the WHERE clause for the join conditions.

If so try:-

```
SELECT CustomerCity 
FROM auth 
LEFT JOIN tb_data.cobs 
ON auth.CustomerCity = cobs.city 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Select *.auth, *.cobs from auth join cobs on auth.city = cobs.city limit 3

Answer (score -1):

The query is incorrect, you need to specify the link betweeen the tables `auth` and `tb_data.cobs.city`. For example:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    FOOTABLE FOO
LEFT JOIN
    BARTABLE BAR ON BAR.FOO_ID FOO.ID = -- here goes the link between them
WHERE
    ...
```